# Facebook integration - Android - Parse

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am using ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.2.jar and everytime I am facing an error in this line:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
```

The error I am facing is below

```
... I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize, referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.<init>

... I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 14412: Lcom/facebook/login/LoginManager;.getInstance ()Lcom/facebook/login/LoginManager;

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 14411: Lcom/facebook/FacebookSdk;.sdkInitialize (Landroid/content/Context;I)V

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/facebook/AccessToken;)

... I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.facebook.AccessToken.getUserId, referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.getAuthData

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14406: Lcom/facebook/AccessToken;.getUserId ()Ljava/lang/String;

... I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult, referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.onActivityResult

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14409: Lcom/facebook/CallbackManager;.onActivityResult (IILandroid/content/Intent;)Z

... I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.restoreAuthentication

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 14412: Lcom/facebook/login/LoginManager;.getInstance ()Lcom/facebook/login/LoginManager;
... E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.AccessToken', referenced from method com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.restoreAuthentication

... W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1749 (Lcom/facebook/AccessToken;) in Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider;
... I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1; interface 1753 'Lcom/facebook/FacebookCallback;'

... W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1;' failed

... W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41823700)

... E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.FacebookSdk
            at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.<init>(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:68)
            at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:96)
            at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:81)
        ...
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you solve the problem???

Answer (score 2):

> Note: ParseFacebookUtils requires Facebook Android SDK v4.x.x
>   [from Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFacebookUtils.html)

```
Could not find method com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize
```

This means you need Facebook SDK also. Parse call function from Facebook SDK which is not exist in your project.